What does it mean when the list of 'Names ' in my package contains a name H4$ for a function which I never wrote?
I have indeed written  a function H4, but the list of 'Names'  contains both  H4, and H4$, the latter being invisible to any type of searches.

What is dollar sign $ used for internally?, What is $ sign in Mathematica?, and many other questions ...

Is it in a pattern variable?

It is the name of a module I wrote, and I do not know what a   pattern variable means

@florin, if you want to get some more concrete help and feedback, you will have to edit the question and include your code. Try to make it as minimal as possible which still reproduces your observation.
